# Highcharts Sparkline chart with dynamic data for table -Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to draw Sparkline chart in table. I just followed the example showed in Highcharts Sparkline demo. I want to draw 2 column data and 3rd column with chart. But instead of static data I used `ng-repeat` in

```
<tr ng-repeat="tablerowdata in tablearray>
   <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in tablerowdata" data-sparkline="{{value}}" >
```

When I try to display value with expression outside, td data is displaying but data is not passing to Sparkline chart.

Example I followed: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline

How to pass dynamic data with key value pair, where key value as xaxis value and value as data.

Comment: I added  ng-repeat in tr and looped key value in td

Comment: Have you considered using Highcharts official wrapper for Angular (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular)? The documentation explains how to perform dynamic chart updates - check out the “update” flag.
Also, could you provide a live demo that recreates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('chartApp', [])
  .controller('ChartController', function($scope,$timeout) {
  
  $scope.contcat_list = [
    {name:'Abdo Hamoud', chart:'1,5,4,2,5,9,3'},
    {name:'Mahmoud Ali', chart:'1,0,7,7,5,9,4'},
    {name:'Tamer Hassan', chart:'1,4,3,7,5,9,3'},
    {name:'Ahmed Sabry', chart:'1,4,0,7,5,9,7'},
    {name:'Khaled Said', chart:'1,0,7,4,5,9,8'}
  ];
  
    $timeout(function(){ $('.inlinesparkline').sparkline(); },100)
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app="chartApp">
  <div ng-controller="ChartController">

    <table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Chart</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in contcat_list">
          <td>{{row.name}}</td>
          <td><div class="inlinesparkline">{{row.chart}}</div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```